# define different variables then merge them with equal values and echo it separately

Tags: php

```
$x = 123;
$y = 456;

$x = $y .= 789;

echo "$x<br>";
echo "$y<br>";
```

In my code here the result is

```
456789
456789
```

But this result isn't what i want, Since it is only `$y` value

What i aim for is to `echo` it separated like this

```
123789
456789
```

Since here i defined `$x` & `$y`then got an equal value, But instead of going `$x .= 789` & `$y .= 789` I just decided to merge them into one, But i got this only `$y` value, How can i fix that?

Comment: Can't you simply do `$x.=789;  $y.=789;`? when you write `$x = $y........` you make y value of x

Comment: @Danielius Well, as i mentioned, I was doing that, But then thought if it is possible to do it in 1 line, So i asked.

Comment: actually you can add variable `$z=789` and make such a nonsense `$x .= substr($y.=$z,strlen($y)-strlen($z),strlen($y));` if you want to do it in one line :D

Comment: but this is not a clever solution

Comment: @Danielius Even tho it would be so much work and nonsense, That actually would be the answer of my question if it works.

Comment: ironical. Yeh it works. Just do not do such stuff because you will overload your brain. Not worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following syntax:

```
$x = $y .= 789;
```

You're appending `789` to `$y`, so you get `456789`. Then you're assigning this result into `$x` - so at the end there are two `456789` values.

You cannot *simplify* this operation in one line - I'd highly suggest to do it in two lines, it's much more clear in understanding.

Comment: you can add this awful solution here: `$x .= substr($y.=$z,strlen($y)-strlen($z),strlen($y));` Even if it is a nonsense and I do not like this way of doing this, this solution is an answer to author's question.

Answer (score 2):

You override the value of `$x`. Assign them separately.
Try this:

```
$x = 123;
$y = 456;

$x .= 789;
$y .= 789;

echo "$x<br>";
echo "$y<br>";
```

Comment: Yes, That what i have, Just was wondering if it is possible to do it in 1 line with both `$x` & `$y` having a different values at first stage, but at second stage merged one.

Answer (score 0):

In your code first you are adding 789 in $y by &y .= 789. Then $y = 456789, After that you assign $y value in $x.
So $x value replaced from 123 to 456789.

You have to do it separately.

```
<?php 
    $x = 123;
    $y = 456;
    $x .= 789; $y .= 789;
    echo "$x<br>";
    echo "$y<br>";
?>
```

Comment: You should add an explanation as well.

Comment: Okay ... Sorry I'm adding